# securing WCF service with OAuth 2.0

Tags: wcf, oauth, owin

I followed the example in the article http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

this works great for WEB API, how would I secure a WCF service the same way? I would like to have it communicate to the authorization server coded with OWIN and WEB API, is there a WCF binding that will communicate with it? or any other way to do this?